# How to reset a global variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a global variable which stores the position of some divs, its initial value is 0.
when i click on a button i add 220px to the 0 to move the content, but i have two of these buttons so when i click on the next button instead of moving the content by 220px it moves it by 440px (meaning the old value wasn't cleared when i clicked on the next button).

is there any another way of solving this?

I would really appreciate if solution is pure javascript

```js
window.onload = function(){

    //CAROUSEL
    var leftSlideBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-left');
    var rightSlideBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-right');
    var flexItems = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-item');
    var flex = document.querySelectorAll('.flex');


    var itemPos = 0;
    var duration = 800;

    ////////////////////////////////////SLIDE FORWARD////////////////////////////////
    for (var i = 0; i < rightSlideBtn.length; i++) {
      rightSlideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', F_slideHandlers);
      rightSlideBtn[i].addEventListener('mousedown', F_TransitionError);

    }


    function F_slideHandlers() {
      var currentClickedBtn = Array.from(rightSlideBtn).indexOf(this);

      var flexID = currentClickedBtn;
      var totalFlexItemWidth = flex[flexID].children[1].offsetLeft - flex[flexID].children[0].offsetLeft;
      var F_overflowedWidth = flex[flexID].scrollWidth - flex[flexID].offsetWidth;
      // console.log(F_overflowedWidth);

      F_slide(flexID, totalFlexItemWidth, F_overflowedWidth);
      F_btnOff();
      F_btnOn();
    }



    function F_slide(id, flexItemFullwidth, F_overflow) {
 
      itemPos -= flexItemFullwidth;
      for (var i = 0; i <   flex[id].children.length; i++) {
        flex[id].children[i].style.left = itemPos + 'px';
          flex[id].children[i].style.transitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
        var overflow = F_overflow + itemPos;

      }
    }


    function F_btnOff() {
      for (let i = 0; i < rightSlideBtn.length; i++) {
        rightSlideBtn[i].removeEventListener('click', F_slideHandlers);
      }
    }

    function F_btnOn() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < rightSlideBtn.length; i++) {
          rightSlideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', F_slideHandlers);
        }
      }, duration);
    }

    function F_TransitionError() {
      F_ErrorFix();
      F_fixed();
    }

    function F_ErrorFix() {
      for (var i = 0; i < flexItems.length; i++) {
        flexItems[i].style.left = itemPos + 'px';
      } 
    }
    function F_fixed() {
      for (var i = 0; i < rightSlideBtn.length; i++) {
        rightSlideBtn[i].removeEventListener('mousedown', F_TransitionError);
      }
    }
}
```

```css
    #wrapper{
      background: #f4f4f4;
      height: 250px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }

    img{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .content-slider-nav-btn{
      position: absolute;
      height: 45px;
      width: 45px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-top: 100px;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 1;
      box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .content-slider-nav-btn:hover {
      background: #000;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.0);
      transition: 500ms ease;
    }
    .content-slider-nav-btn:active {
      background: transparent;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      transition: 500ms ease;
      /* box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 1px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
    }
    .content-slider-nav-btn i {
      margin-top: 13px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    .nav-left {
      left: 10px;
      display: none; 
    }
    .nav-right {
      right: 10px;
    }

    .flex {
      max-height: 300px;
      width: 95%;
      background: #fafafa;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
     .flex-item {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 200px;
      min-width: 210px;
      max-height: 230px;
      max-width: 220px;
      background: #ddd;
      margin-right: 10px;
      box-shadow: 1px 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      /* transition-duration: 800ms; */
      transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    .flex-item:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SLIDE FIX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="wrapper">

      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"><</i></div>
      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right">></i></div>

      <div class="flex">

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-0</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-1</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-2</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-3</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-4</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-5</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-6</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-7</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-8</a></h1>
        </div>        

      </div>
    </section>

   
    <section id="wrapper">

      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"><</i></div>
      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right">></i></div>

      <div class="flex">

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-0</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-1</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-2</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-3</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-4</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-5</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-6</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-7</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-8</a></h1>
        </div>        

      </div>
    </section>   

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code should be in the question to preserve your questions long-term value.  Not linked to.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read through ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post accordingly - you've done half the work by describing the problem, but you still need to show your code, and explain what you've already tried to fix this yourself (and why you feel that didn't work, if it didn't work)

Comment: Before assigning real values assigne 0 again first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the comments are placed within this fiddle, not too comfortable with SO's manner of dealing with multi level code, but placing it here as well. Comments held within the code relay most of the changes and their reason, and repeating them here would feel unneeded.

https://jsfiddle.net/Luis_Perez64/qzr9yjud/

```js
window.onload = function(){
//CAROUSEL
let leftSlideBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-left');
let rightSlideBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-right');
let flexElements = document.querySelectorAll('.flex');
let itemPos = [];
let duration = 800;


////////////////////////////////////SLIDE FORWARD////////////////////////////////
for (let i = 0; i < rightSlideBtn.length; i++) {
  /* 
  Instead of dealing with global vars which are more than not warned against,
  It comes out better to just pass in your variables.
  Reason for the functions is to keep the context of this scope technically global,
  and pass in/through the variables cleanly.
   */
  rightSlideBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    F_slideHandlers(flexElements[i], i)
  });

  // NOTE: Commented out the remove event listener from the code below, never resuscribes although it happens only on first pull.
  rightSlideBtn[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    F_TransitionError(flexElements[i], i)
  });
  /* 
  Using an array to handle your positioning, because there could be multiple elements and each should have their own thought
  on what their position is. The manner in which you were seeking to solve this would
   require counters, and arithmetic to keep within just one variable. 
   
   // NOTE: !!!! This is more than likely the main change that you'd have to make to your initial implementation, but everything else comes in as heavy, personal, recommendations.
   */
  itemPos.push(0)
}


function F_slideHandlers(flex, idx) {
  let totalFlexItemWidth = flex.children[1].offsetLeft - flex.children[0].offsetLeft;
  let F_overflowedWidth = flex.scrollWidth - flex.offsetWidth;

  F_slide(flex, totalFlexItemWidth, F_overflowedWidth, idx);
  // NOTE: Why are these two functions needed? Adding and removing event listeners
  F_btnOff(flex, idx);
  F_btnOn(flex, idx);
}



function F_slide(flexItem, flexItemFullwidth, F_overflow, idx) {
  itemPos[idx] -= flexItemFullwidth;
  for (let i = 0; i < flexItem.children.length; i++) {
    flexItem.children[i].style.left = itemPos[idx] + 'px';
    flexItem.children[i].style.transitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
  }
}


function F_btnOff(flex, idx) {
  /* rightSlideBtn[idx] && rightSlideBtn[idx].removeEventListener('click', () => F_slideHandlers(flex, idx)); */
}

function F_btnOn(flex, idx) {
  /* 
  setTimeout(function() {
    rightSlideBtn[idx] && rightSlideBtn[idx].addEventListener('click', () => F_slideHandlers(flex, idx));
  } , duration);
  */
}

function F_TransitionError(flex, idx) {
  F_ErrorFix(flex, idx);
  F_fixed(flex, idx);
}

function F_ErrorFix(flexItems, idx) {
  for (let i = 0; i < flexItems.length; i++) {
    flexItems[i].style.left = itemPos[idx] + 'px';
  }
}

function F_fixed(flex, idx) {
  // NOTE: I feel the only real reason for this was to fix the overrun caused by multiple event listeners grabbing and mutating that itemPosition variable initially. 
  for (let i = 0; i < rightSlideBtn.length; i++) {
    /* rightSlideBtn[i].removeEventListener('mousedown', () => F_TransitionError(flex, idx)) */
    ;
  }
}

 }
```

```css
    #wrapper{
      background: #f4f4f4;
      height: 250px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }

    img{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .content-slider-nav-btn{
      position: absolute;
      height: 45px;
      width: 45px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-top: 100px;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 1;
      box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .content-slider-nav-btn:hover {
      background: #000;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.0);
      transition: 500ms ease;
    }
    .content-slider-nav-btn:active {
      background: transparent;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      transition: 500ms ease;
      /* box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 1px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
    }
    .content-slider-nav-btn i {
      margin-top: 13px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    .nav-left {
      left: 10px;
      display: none; 
    }
    .nav-right {
      right: 10px;
    }

    .flex {
      max-height: 300px;
      width: 95%;
      background: #fafafa;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
     .flex-item {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 200px;
      min-width: 210px;
      max-height: 230px;
      max-width: 220px;
      background: #ddd;
      margin-right: 10px;
      box-shadow: 1px 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      /* transition-duration: 800ms; */
      transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    .flex-item:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SLIDE FIX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="wrapper">

      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"><</i></div>
      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right">></i></div>

      <div class="flex">

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-0</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-1</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-2</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-3</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-4</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-5</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-6</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-7</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-8</a></h1>
        </div>        

      </div>
    </section>

   
    <section id="wrapper">

      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"><</i></div>
      <div class="content-slider-nav-btn nav-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right">></i></div>

      <div class="flex">

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-0</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-1</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-2</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-3</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-4</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-5</a></h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-6</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-7</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1 class="content-slider-title"><a href="#">item-8</a></h1>
        </div>        

      </div>
    </section>   

  </body>
</html>
```